# robot_enable error motoman

Tags: ros, motoman-driver, motoman, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

After setting all the things with controller dx100 and driver launch, when I call rosservice robot_enable I am getting this error,

```
Failed to set TrajectoryMode: Not Ready (5) : Unable to enable drive power (5006)
Motoman robot was NOT enabled. Please re-examine and retry.
```

am I missing something to load?

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321995/robot_enable-error-motoman/) by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2019-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> Unable to enable drive power (5006)
> ```

From the robot controller's perspective, the ROS nodes are no different from other "external" sources of control (a PLC fi).

So all the same safety systems are in place and you need to take care of all the same safety requirements.

The error message tells you that the controller has determined that it cannot enable motor power and therefore the `robot_enable` service call returns an error.

The [Usage: Robot Controller](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver/Tutorials/Usage#Robot_Controller) section of the *Using the Motoman FS/DX/YRC ROS Interface* tutorial lists the minimum requirements for external control to be possible:

> Prior to executing ROS motion:

> 1. Make sure the robot controller is ready:
>
> - Installation and setup of MotoROS driver must be complete
>   -  Pendant key switch must be in Remote mode
>   - The E-stop latch must be released

Furthermore the standard safety conditions must be met: any fences closed, all e-stops released (also external ones), and no inhibiting devices (ie: a PLC) can be actively keeping the robot in an error state.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-04-26**:
@gvdhoorn prior to executing ROS motion minimum requirements I have checked and its all ok. Also, I found that no one has experience this type of error on github issues and google groups.

so, how can I solve this?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-26**:
Can you enable your servos manually with the Pendant in Remote mode?

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-04-26**:
that I will check on monday and let you know, as I don't have access right now due to weekend.

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-04-29**:
thank you. the reason was this, "safety guard is open", after closing this it is working.